# Regex with any character in front and after given string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've got the following text: `Unbekannter Fehler: while trying to invoke the method test() of a null object loaded from local variable 'libInfo'`

```
Matcher matcher = null;
Pattern pattern = null;
try
{
    pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + "Unbekannter Fehler: while trying to invoke the method test() of a null object loaded from local variable 'libInfo'" + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE & Pattern.DOTALL);
    matcher = pattern.matcher("Unbekannter Fehler: while trying to invoke the method test() of a null object loaded from local variable 'libInfo'");

    if (matcher.matches())
        System.out.println("Same!");
}
```

If I run the above code, it returns `false`, but why? I just want to check, if the text is contained by the other one with regular expression (No `String.contains(...)`). If I read it properly, I have to use `.*` at the beginning and at the end of the regex to be sure, that it neverminds, what is coming in front or after the string to check.

Comment: Keep removing characters from your pattern till it matches, then you will know what characters are causing it to not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all of your characters are properly escaped first. Try using `Pattern#quote`

```
String test = "Unbekannter Fehler: while trying to invoke the method test() of a null object loaded from local variable 'libInfo'";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*" + Pattern.quote(test)  + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE & Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Same!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the parentheses in the pattern.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("Unbekannter Fehler: while trying to invoke the method test\\(\\) of a null object loaded from local variable 'libInfo'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE & Pattern.DOTALL);
```

You shouldn't need the `.*` at the beginning, nor the end though.

Regards